# Проблема с сессиями в PHP

Tags: php, сессия

Пользователь вводит данные в форме, потом данные идут в обработчик если всё ок, то перенаправляемый на страницу с его профилем. В профиле ничего не выводиться, проверял функцией Isset на переменную $login, false. В обработчике -

```
<?php
    session_start();
//  вся процедура работает на сессиях. Именно в ней хранятся данные  пользователя, пока он находится на сайте.
Очень важно запустить их в  самом начале странички!!!

    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $login = $_POST['login'];

        if($login == '')
        {
            unset($login);
        }
    }
//заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную

    if(isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($password == '')
        {
            unset($password);
        }
    }
//заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную

    if(empty($login) or empty($password))
    //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт

    {
        exit("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
    }
//если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут
ввести
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
//удаляем лишние пробелы
    $login = trim($login);
    $password = trim($password);
// подключаемся к базе
    include ("db.php");
// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'", $db);
//извлекаем из базы все данные о пользователе с введенным логином
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if(empty($myrow['password']))
    {
//если пользователя с введенным логином не существует
        exit("Извините, введённый вами login или пароль неверный.");
    }
    else 
    {
//если существует, то сверяем пароли

        if($myrow['password'] == $password)
        {
//если пароли совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию! Можете его поздравить, он вошел!
            $login = $_SESSION['login'] = $myrow['login'];
            $id = $_SESSION['id'] = $myrow['id'];
//эти данные очень часто используются, вот их и будет "носить с собой" вошедший пользователь
            header("Location: profile.php");
        }
        else 
        {
//если пароли не сошлись
            exit("Извините, введённый вами login или пароль неверный.");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Вызвал, в начале страницы

Comment: @angers777, в начале обоих страниц?

Comment: Да, в обоих

Comment: выбрось курсы попова!

Comment: Я не по Попову

Comment: @angers777, вы бы привели больше кода, а то остается только гадать: а считываете ли вы значение с $_SESSION, не делаете ли вы это точно как в обработчике, не идёт ли считывание до старта сессии, включены ли у вас вообще куки и т.п.

Comment: Код в студию!

Comment: Код в студии =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быть может, вы не вызвали [`session_start()`](http://ua.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)?
Эта функция как раз **создает** или **восстанавливает** сессию. Без неё никаких параметров в `$_SESSION` не будет.

Там же написано, что идентификатор сессии передается через GET, POST или в Cookies. Отключены куки - нет сессии.

Как вариант, стоит протестировать это всё без влияния других ваших действий.

В начале **обработчика** допишите:

```
session_start();
$login = $_SESSION['login'] = 'MyLogin';
$id = $_SESSION['id'] = 123;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($login);
var_dump($id);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
die;
```

В **профиле** (profile.php, я полагаю):

```
session_start();
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($login);
var_dump($id);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
die;
```

После этого отправляйте форму и смотрите на вывод. Переходите на profile.php и опять же - вывод. **Анализируйте**.

Comment: Вывело Null Null

Comment: В обработчике:
string(7) "MyLogin"
int(123)

Comment: Проверьте наличие куки PHPSESSID находясь на странице profile.php. Если не в курсе как - смотрите новую строчку в ответе:

    var_dump($_COOKIE);

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Объявил сессии в профиле, помогло!=)

Comment: :) хм.. а говорили, что объявили

Comment: Я в обработчике объявил, не знал что на каждой странице нужно объявлять, думал что одного раза достаточно

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    $login = $_SESSION['login'];
}
// и т.д.
```